# Trying to create a new property via REST API

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, sharepoint-rest-api, error, property-bag

My SharePoint buddy has created a new property in a SharePoint Online site for me called `IsArchived`. I can query that property using this REST API call:

```
GET https://mycompany.sharepoint.com/sites/mysite/_api/web/allproperties?$select=IsArchived
```

I get back a JSON response something like:

```
{
    "odata.metadata": "https://mycompany.sharepoint.com/sites/mysite/_api/$metadata#SP.ApiData.PropertyValuess/@Element&$select=IsArchived",
    "odata.type": "SP.PropertyValues",
    "odata.id": "https://mycompany.sharepoint.com/sites/mysite/_api/web/allproperties",
    "odata.editLink": "web/allproperties",
    "IsArchived": "Yes"
}
```

I was now trying to create/update that property in another SharePoint Online site, with this `POST` request:

```
POST https://mycompany.sharepoint.com/sites/myothersite/_api/web
```

Headers:

```
"Accept":"application/json;odata=verbose"
"If-Match":"*"
"X-HTTP-Method":"MERGE"
```

Body:

```
{
    "IsArchived": false, "__metadata": { "type": "SP.PropertyValues" }
}
```

Unfortunately, I only get this response:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "-1, Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.InvalidClientQueryException",
        "message": {
            "lang": "de-DE",
            // translated to en-US by me
            "value": "The property \"IsArchived\" is not present for type \"SP.Web\". Please ensure to use only property names that are defined in the type."
        }
    }
}
```

What exactly is SharePoint trying to tell me here? (I'm not a very extensive SharePoint user or developer - usually, it's a major struggle to get anything from SharePoint ... as seen here, once again ...)

Comment: Was it created using SharePoint REST API for first site?

Comment: Check [this](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/143692/adding-property-bag-value-with-rest) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18249460/sharepoint-2013-property-bag-crud-using-jquery-rest-api-and-csom-ecmascript) and see if it helps.

Comment: @GaneshSanap-MVP: I believe for the first site, my buddy used PowerShell to create that new property and set it to a specific value. But since he mentioned he didn't have to create the property explicitly, before setting its value, I was hoping I could do the same using the REST API from C#

Comment: Links I shared above suggests that it is not possible using REST API. Maybe you need to use PowerShell or JSOM. I know this can be done easily using [Set-PnPPropertyBagValue](https://pnp.github.io/powershell/cmdlets/Set-PnPPropertyBagValue.html?wt.mc_id=MVP_315224) command in PnP PowerShell.